# import data from web to Excel 2010 worksheet

Tags: windows, vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to import data from web to Excel worksheet on win 7.

But, I do not know how to finish the left one where is marked .

```
Sub Ex2Macro()

    Ex2 from Macro1 Macro
    ' Macro changed 17/07/2007 by Dr. B. I. Czaczkes
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim temp As Variant ' Double
    Set qt = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
      "URL;http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=GBPUSD=X", Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1"))
    With qt
    .Name = "query1"
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .SaveData = True
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "14"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With
  With qt.ResultRange
    .ClearContents
    .Range("a1").Value = "USD/GBP"
    .Range("b1").Value = ?     ' here, what I should put so that the queried result             
                               ' is printed ? 
  End With
End Sub
```

---

Another piece of code that provide the exchange result.

```
Sub Ex3Macro()
  Dim qt As QueryTable
  ' Dim temp As Double
  Dim temp As Variant
  temp = ActiveCell.Value
  Set qt = Worksheets("temp").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://finance.yahoo.com/currency/convert?amt=" & _
    temp & _
    "&from=USD&to=GBP&submit=Convert" _
    , Destination:=Worksheets("Temp").Range("a1"))
  With qt
    .Name = "query2"
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .SaveData = True
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "13"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With
  ActiveCell.Range("b1").Value = qt.ResultRange.Range("e3").Value
End Sub
```

But, no result is printed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `Destination` should be `ActiveSHEET.Range` not `ActiveCell.Range`.  That said, when I run this, the result of QueryTables is that NO DATA imported to Excel. What are you trying to do?

Comment: QueryTables brings in the full web page, no? I would use another method creating an instance of IE and then parsing the HTML elements to find the one containing the exchange rate.

Comment: Does the second one work? I suspect not.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1 reference then using this:

```
Sub HTTPTest()

Dim httpRequest As WinHttpRequest
Dim URL As String, strHTML As String

If httpRequest Is Nothing Then
    Set httpRequest = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
End If

URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=GBPUSD=X"

httpRequest.Open "GET", URL, True
httpRequest.Send
httpRequest.WaitForResponse
strHTML = httpRequest.ResponseText
Set httpRequest = Nothing

'Parse strHTML now to get your value

End Sub
```